# Redux Framework in Wordpress not working

Tags: php, wordpress, redux-framework

I don't know what is wrong with me. I just simple generated a file using build.reduxframework.com and then added in my Wordpress theme. Then added the following line to functions.php

```
if(is_admin()){
    require_once(get_template_directory().'/core/admin/admin-init.php');
}
```

Good thing is the demo stuff is showing up. Now my $opt_name is for_test. In my header.php I am adding the following code.

```
<h2><?php
global $for_test;
echo $for_test['textarea-example'];
?></h2>
```

PS: textarea-example is the id of the field which is already added in the files I downloaded. But I don't know why it is not fetching the value in it.

Answer (score 0):

is_admin() means that only admins will load that. So if you're logged out, your redux config will never load.

Best to just include it. Redux will take care of when it should run.